# Filtration generated by two-dimensional processes

Tags: probability, filtrations

The following question seems intuitively true to me but I would appreciate if someone could provide a through/rigorous explanation:

Let f(t) and g(t) be continuous-time processes defined on the same sample space: Is the filtration generated by (f(t),g(t)) the same as that generated by (f(t),f(t)+g(t))?

More generally, when will the filtration generated by a function of a stochastic process be the same as the one generated by the original process?

Many thanks

Comment: When you know $f(t)$ and $f(t)+g(t)$ do you know $g(t)\,?$ This will answer the first question. Regarding the second question: When you know $|f(t)|$ and $|g(t)|$ how about $f(t)$ and $g(t)\,?$